# Android handle large fonts in layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, font-size

I would like to know how to handle layouts when user changes the fonts size.
actually I know I can create different layouts for different screens size and different orientations, but what about if users large fonts?

Thank you

Comment: If you're talking about the phone's font settings then there is nothing you should do. User should have the right to set the large font. What if he/she has a vision issue? Test your app with the large font set through the phone's settings and make sure you've provide appropriate values for your layouts preventing their break.

Comment: Yes this is the point, I don't want block/prevent those changes, my question (maybe is not clear, sorry for my bad english) is about how can I handle this situation.

I have a relative layout with a many textview (title and values) aligned each other. If I set large font from settings everithing is unreadable, if I reduce the font-size into the xml layout file, I gain an extra space between labels, unwanted and ugly to see, but well paginated with large font size (in settings)

Comment: No, I got you, you were pretty clear. What I'm trying to say is that from what I've read so far you can't do anything about it unless you make your layouts "smarter" (like scrolling, ellipsizing views etc).

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do other than make your layouts scrollable.

On one side this is a design nightmare, on the other hand, some people can't see well..